# What the correct way when use Double-Checked Locking with memory barrier in c++?

Tags: c++, singleton, double-checked-locking

I just read the excellent blog [C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405772)

And I don't understand why we have to use the first memory barrier in Example 12 (as below):

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance () {
       Singleton* tmp = pInstance;
       ... // insert memory barrier
       if (tmp == 0) {
          Lock lock;
          tmp = pInstance;
          if (tmp == 0) {
             tmp = new Singleton;
             ... // insert memory barrier
             pInstance = tmp;
          }
       }
       return tmp;
    }
```

Is it safe to change it to code below? Why not?

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance () {
       if (pInstance == 0) {
          Lock lock;
          if (pInstance == 0) {
             Singleton* tmp = new Singleton;
             ... // insert memory barrier
             pInstance = tmp;
          }
       }
       return pInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't safe.  Reading the three paragraphs before the example, and the two after it, the potential problem is a system where the write to `pInstance` is done (flushed to memory) on thread B before the construction of `Singleton` has been flushed.  Then thread A could read `pInstance`, see the pointer as non-null, and return it potentially allowing thread A to access the `Singleton` before thread B has finished storing it into memory.

The first flush is necessary to ensure that the flushing of the writes during construction of `Singleton` have been completed *before* you try to use it in a different thread.

Depending on the hardware you're running on this might not be a problem.

Comment: isn’t the second barrier guarantee that pInstance always stored after tmp’s construction is done?

Comment: It does for thread B, but the hardware cache could flush out the update to `pInstance` before all of the writes during Singleton construction have been flushed to main memory.  Then thread A (running on a different CPU) would see the update value of `pInstance` but not the fully constructed Singleton.  This is what the paragraph 3 above the example mentions.

Comment: so the second barrier makes sure that the execution (in thread X) is in right order as it's written (construct, then assign to `pInstance`), not reordered by compiler. and the first barrier makes sure that another thread (Y) will see the value  in the same order as it assigned in thread X?

Comment: Yes, by ensuring that all previous writes by thread X can be seen by thread Y.

Comment: If I add a memory barrier as the first statement of my second `Singleton::instance ()` function, then is it become safe now?

Comment: No.  If thread X gets past the memory barrier, thread Y writes to `pInstance`, then thread X reads `pInstance` you still have a potential problem.  This is why the original code reads `pInstance` into `tmp` before the barrier.